# Altura de bloque contenedor igual al mínimo contenido

Tags: html, css

Partiendo de un bloque que contiene a su vez varios bloques, la pregunta es si CSS puede poner la altura del bloque contenedor al mismo valor que la altura del bloque contenido más pequeño, el otro tendría un overflow.
A modo de ejemplo:

```
 <table class="tabla">
   <thead class="head">
      <tr class="seccion">
        <th class="item">Columna 1</th>
        <th class="item">Columna 2</th>
        <th class="item">Columna 3</th>
        <th class="item">Columna 4</th>
        <th class="item">Columna 5</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody class="body">
      <tr class="seccion">
        <td class="item">item del der-1:1</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-1:2</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-1:3</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-1:4</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-1:5</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr class="seccion">
        <td class="item">item del der-2:1</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-2:2</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-2:3</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-2:4</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-2:5</td>
      </tr>        
      <tr class="seccion">
        <td class="item">item del der-3:1</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-3:2</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-3:3</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-3:4</td>
        <td class="item">item del der-3:5</td>
      </tr>        
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Con este CSS serían dos columnas: una mas corta que la otra.

```
 .tabla{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 4px;
    height:  min-content;
    overflow-y:hidden;
  }
  .head, .body{ 
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
  }
  .head{
    height: min-content;
  }
.body{
      /*height: 146px;*/
      overflow-y:scroll;
}
  .head .seccion{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction:column;
     row-gap: 4px;
  }
  .body .seccion{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction:column;
     row-gap: 4px;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
  .body .seccion:last-child{
    margin-bottom:0
  }
.item{
  padding: 4px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

Si en la clase **tabla** o en la clase **body** pongo la altura comentada (146px, la altura de **head**) se ve el efecto que busco: un lateral fijo y otro deslizante. Pero la cuestión es como hacer esto sin poner la altura de manera absoluta, sino que sea CSS quien calcule esa altura para la tabla o body, provocando el overflow vertical de body.
CSS tendría que obtener la altura de la **tabla** (o de **body**) a partir de la altura de **head**
Se que este layout se puede hacer de otras formas (sidebars, posciones static..), pero quiero usar este layout.
Se que es posible hacerlo con Javascript, pero mi idea es ver si CSS puede hacerlo solo.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Probaste con `height: fit-content;`

Comment: fit-conten, calcula el height a partir del contenido, pero procura ajustar el contenedor al contenido  completo, evita el overflow. Lo mismo pasa con min- y max- content.